# TRichEdit and Unicode - different behavior on XP and Win7

Tags: delphi, unicode, windows-7, richedit

In non-unicode Delphi (I've tried with D7 and D2006):

1. Put a TRichEdit on the form and run the application
2. Switch to some "exotic" keyboard layout (Russian, Greek, whatever)
3. Type something

On XP, everything is good and I can see normal Russian letters. However, on Win7 characters are wrong (accented letters from other languages). If I copy Russian text from MS Word and paste it to RichEdit, it looks OK.

I suspect it is something related to RichEdit control version, but it there any way to overcome it? If possible, I would like to avoid switching to TTntRichEdit (which appears to work correctly), as I would need to change lots of existing code.

Comment: Seems to work fine with D5 on my Win7 x64. Though, if you switch keyboards while the program is running, the application doesn't detect it.

Comment: This may not be relevant but have you seen this [Francois](http://stackoverflow.com/users/9842/francois) post about using different version [blogpost](http://fgaillard.com/2010/09/using-richedit-4-1-with-d2010/)

Comment: Thanks Merlin, no I haven't saw that one. I'll try to follow it.

Comment: You want to use a non-unicode control in a unicode windows version, and use MBCS with Russian? What's your code page? You ARE AWARE that the TRichEdit control on Delphi 7 is an MBCS version, not a UNICODE version, and that this is the most likely cause of your confusion and your problems. CodePages matter deeply in MBCS/AnsiString Delphi.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use converions like `AnsiToUtf8` or `AnsiToUnicode`, when user presses a key.

Comment: In OnKeyPress? Thanks, but no, it doesn't work, which is not surprising for me, as Key argument is Char and I can't put two-byte char into it. Unless there's some other way to intercept a message?

Comment: It probably got an upvote in the review queue where I found it between first posts. That's just disadvantage of that queue...